# Is There a Point When $\frac{\ln^{2.3\sin x}}{2^{\sin x}}+0.5\in \mathbb{Z}$ when $x\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

## Introduction

Hello, All!

I was scrolling through YouTube where a video's thumbnail asked if it was possible to miss all the corners (ie, integer outputs for integer inputs) and was title *Why We Care About Functions*. I misunderstood what the video was about so challenged myself to create a function that would do just that. The function I came up with was
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln^{2.3\sin x}x}{2^{\sin x}}+0.5$$

When playing around with it on Desmos, I found that, seemingly, no integer $\leq2\times10^{8}$ returns $(x, f(x))$ where $x, f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now, I'm not a mathematician but I enjoy the artform of it, so I was curious if anyone could think of what an integer input that yields an integer output.

## What I Tried

Instinctually in creating the function, I knew that using sine waves would be beneficial because they are transcendental. Furthermore, since the natural log is using a transcendental number as its base, I would assume that most of the outputs for integers would also be transcendental (or at the very least not rational). Thus, I conjecture that only a power of $e$ would do the trick, but that would require a few things, viz, that

1. $\sin x$ returns either an integer that would make $2.3$ a whole number (viz, $10$)
2. $x$ is either an integer power of $e$ or returns a value when raised to the power of $2.3\sin x$ will give an integer, and
3. The result of the all of the manipulations of $x$ would result in a number that $\equiv 0.5\mod1$

### Use of the Complex Definition of Sine

First, I considered the complex definition of sine: $\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and found that this would change the function to the following:
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[2i]{\frac{\ln x}{2}}\ln^{e^{ix}}(x-2)}{\sqrt[e^{ix}]{\ln(x-2)}}$$

Looking at this formula, I decided that there wasn't much use to me gleaned from it outside of the fact that $e$ appears everywhere and, seemingly, $2$ is not a viable input, but this is not true since $f(2)\approx0.747388269433$. The fact that $e$ and $i$ are everywhere indicate to me that this formula would require transcendental numbers (or at the very least irrational numbers) to accomplish this goal which lines up with the idea that a natural number would be represented by $r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$ where $\theta=k\tau, k\in\mathbb{Z}, \tau=2\pi$.

### Considering When Natural Log Returns an Integer & Its Value When Raised to $2.3\sin x$

Due to the Rules of Logarithms, I know that $\log_b a\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $a=b^n\land n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we know that $\ln x\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $x=e^n$. Since $e^n\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can conclude that $\ln x$ will never return an integer.

In contrast to this, I considered $2.3\sin x$. Because this just scales the sine function to have a range of $[-2.3, 2.3]$ but still hitting the points $\{0, 2.3, 0, -2.3\}$ at $\{0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}\}+k\tau$ when $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can see that it is still transcendental. However, we can find when it hits $1$ or $-1$. Solving for these, we find that it does so when $x=\arcsin\left(\frac{\pm1}{2.3} \right)\approx\pm0.449796860424$, also a transcendental number.

Alternatively, I considered when $\sin x=\frac{\pm1}{2.3}$ so it would cancel out the exponent and yield $1$. Unfortunately, this happens when $x\approx\pm0.190180268996$, another transcendental number.

## Conclusion

Based on the work I've done here so far, I think that it is impossible for this function to cross a corner on the grid, thus making the function a success in that it never hits a corner, but this is just my conjecture based on the work that I've done. As I said, I'm not a mathematician so I very likely overlooked something, but this feels air-tight to me.

So, knowing that I'm not a professional nor even particularly well-versed in advanced mathematics, I was curious if any of you may be able to see if there is a time when $x, f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}$, but I simply don't see it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "$\sin(x)$ returns either an integer that would make $2.3$ a whole number (viz, $10$)" - This is impossible, for the range (i.e. range of outputs) of $\sin(x)$ is a real number in the box $[-1, +1]$, $\forall x$ as input. The best scenario in this sense is $\sin(x) = 0$. Yet in this case $x = 0 + 2 k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, which does exclude the possibility for $x$ to be an integer.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps I should have said 'eg, $10$'. This very issue is discussed in the section where I considered the natural log and the outputs of $2.3\sin x$. In fact, it's the fact that $2.3\sin x$ seemingly requires a transcendental number to get an output in $\{0, \frac{\pm1}{2.3}\}$ that makes me think that eliminating the exponent is impossible given the parameters of the problem (ie, where $x\in\mathbb{Z}$)